# How to get custom object id dynamically using apex

Tags: custom-object, tooling-api, dynamic-apex

How to get custom object id dynamically. I have created one button on UI called Create custom field and on click of that button, I want to redirect it to that custom object field creation page(object manager->field and relationships-> new). I cannot give hardcoded id to that link and also it's not taking API name. for API name its showing insufficient privileges.
Is it possible using tooling API? and How?

Comment: Where you will use the button?

Comment: In the lightning web component. for App exchange app.

Comment: And the Lightning component will be used On record page or home page or App Page?

Comment: Lightning web component will be used on the app page!

Comment: I think '/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/Object_Api_Name/FieldsAndRelationships/new' will work if you pass the object api name dynamically.

Comment: how dynamically?

Comment: I have used it as url button on record page and hardcoded the object api name, its working perfectly.  To answer how you can pass dynamically inside a lwc, you need to give more insight on your problem. Like, How you will decide which object field should get created?

Comment: its a custom object. I want to fetch that custom object's id dynamically and pass it in lwc component to onclick action. Its an app so many users will use that app so i cannot give the hardcoded id!

Answer (score 1):

you may try to use the following SOQL Query to get the Id:

Id myCustomObjectId = [SELECT CustomObjectId FROM CustomObjectUserLicenseMetrics WHERE CustomObjectName ='MyCustomObjectName' limit 1].id;

hope it helps

Comment: It's not working!

Answer (score 0):

yes instead of getting the id of the object and redirecting the page to create a custom field, you can create a field using Tooling api itself. I have written a lightning component to create custom object fields for any object (Whichever is accessible to create custom fields). Let me know if you need the code.

Comment: I have done that too but the requirement is to only give button which will redirect to that page.

Answer (score 0):

Just got to know we can query like this.
Got the result using this-

SELECT DurableId FROM EntityDefinition WHERE QualifiedApiName = 'CustomObject__c'